# WebView Text size is Getting Reduced some time after upating the system webview kit

Tags: android

In my application I am using the web view to load a HTML content from the API. it working fine but after updating the system web view sometimes the web content text size is reducing.aAlso occurring frequently. When I uninstall the  update it will work fine please anyone suggest a solution for this.